# How to show just the google map in a WebView

Tags: android, webview

the following code displays the following map in a WebView...

```
    LocateBrowser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.locatebrowser);
LocateBrowser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
WebSettings webSettings = LocateBrowser.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
LocateBrowser.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?z=17&t=h&q=loc:31.8526,-110.9959");
```

[image: example map]

the problem is that all of those buttons along the top and bottom take up screen real estate on the small WebView display.  How can I get rid of them?
(if the answer is that I have to use javascript then I'll just switch to a mapView)
Thanks,
Gary

Comment: yes you are right you have to use script.. but you dont need to write a long one just right this ** disableDefaultUI:true** this will disable all. for more customization visit. http://www.w3schools.com/googleAPI/google_maps_controls.asp

Comment: their example of disableDefaultUI is a page of code including a map key like we use in the MapView control.  Where does the code go in an android project - they don't mention that.